# Scala - have List of String, must split by comma, and put into Map

Tags: scala, csv, data-structures

I have a List of the form: ("string,num", "string,num", ...)

I have found solutions online for how to do this with a single string, but have not been able to adapt it to a list of strings.

Also, numerical values should be cast to Int/Double before being mapped.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect job for a `fold`

```
// Your input
val lines = List("a,1", "b,2", "gretzky,99", "tyler,11")

// Fold over the lines, and insert them into a map
val map = lines.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]) {
  case (map, line) =>

    // Split the line on the comma and separate the two parts
    val Array(string, num) = line.split(",")

    // Add new entry to the map
    map + (string -> num.toInt)
}

println(map)
```

Output:

```
Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, gretzky -> 99, tyler -> 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best way to do that, but it should meet your needs

```
yourlist.groupBy( _.split(',')(0) ).mapValues(v=>v(0).split(',')(1))
```